# Solving a finite Hilbert transform from 2D thin wing theory

Tags: integral-equations, integral-transforms

I have a problem where I know $w(x) =1$ and want to find $u(x)$. It's a well-known problem I am recreating, from a 1972 paper. Note the paper doesn't solve the problem, the integral equation, it just cites its solution in older work.

> Richard M. James *[On the remarkable accuracy of the vortex lattice method](https://doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(72)90021-7)* Comput. Methods Appl. Mech. Eng. 1, 59–79 (1972)

$$
w(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{u(\text{xx})}{x-\text{xx}} \, d\text{xx}
$$
$$
u(1)=0
$$

I also know the answer,

$$
u(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}
$$

I can work it backwards to verify (it takes a while)

```
u[x_] := 1/π Sqrt[(1 - x)/x]
Assuming[0 <= x <= 1, Integrate[u[xx]/(x - xx), {xx, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]]
```

> `1`

But no joy trying to run it forwards. Tried the following, including wild spitballs:

```
DSolve[1 == Integrate[uu[xx]/(y - xx), {xx, 0, 1}], uu[xx], xx]

DSolve[{1 == Integrate[uu[xx]/(y - xx), {xx, 0, 1}], uu[1] == 0}, uu[xx], xx]

DSolve[1 == Integrate[uu[xx]/(y - xx), {xx, 0, 1}], uu[y], y]

DSolve[{1 == Integrate[uu[xx]/(y - xx), {xx, 0, 1}], uu[1] == 0}, uu[y], y]

DSolve[
  1 == Integrate[uu[xx]/(x - xx), {xx, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True], 
  uu[xx], xx]
```

Did a little digging here on Hilbert transforms, but this is a finite Hilbert transform. Didn't see any obvious questions that mirrored this one. Any ideas? I assume I am posing it wrong, as it doesn't seem like it'd be that hard to solve, based on the simplicity of the answer. But math can be surprising.

So can I solve this integral equation in symbolic form using Mathematica?

Comment: Can you link to the paper, for reference?

Comment: Updated to add the link, a 1972 paper.

Comment: @MikeY At first glance, the article describes in detail the numerical solution method. What is the problem?

Comment: The numerical solution method approaches the idealized result, which is the equation referenced above. I just thought I would use Mathematica to confirm the result myself (and then do some other stuff) and was unable to do so. In short, am I using `DSolve` to solve the integral equation correctly? Wondered if it was my implementation, or something deeper.